# android ui is not updating from ui Thread in api 10 after animation

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

i want to change image of ImageView inside of a DialogFragment every 1s ; 
the code is running ok in android 5 or 4 . but in android 2.3.7 (api 10) it changes ui for once and then doesnt change ui anymore .meanwhile thread is running okay
so far , i tried handler message method with a Timer , handler normal method , runOnUIThread . View.Post method but no luck

```
Bitmap[] onItems = new Bitmap[3];
Bitmap[] offItems= new Bitmap[3];
ImageView[] cheatHoldrs = new ImageView[3];
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


//all Bitmaps and ImageView has been inited
myMethod();


}
```

View.Post Method :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        cheatHoldrs[j].post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                random Random = new Random();
                cheatHoldrs[j].setImageBitmap((random.nextInt(3) % 3 == 1) ? onItems[j]
                        : offItems[j]);
                cheatHoldrs[j].postDelayed(this, 1000);

            }
        });
    }
```

RunOnUIThread

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Random random = new Random();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                cheatHoldrs[j]
                        .setImageBitmap((random.nextInt(3) % 3 == 1) ? onItems[j]
                                : offItems[j]);
            new Handler().postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Noraml Handler method :

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                cheatHoldrs[j]
                        .setImageBitmap((random.nextInt(3) % 3 == 1) ? onItems[j]
                                : offItems[j]);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);    
        }
    });
```

Handler Message Method :{
in global scope :

```
public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cheatHoldrs[j]
                    .setImageBitmap((random.nextInt(3) % 3 == 1) ? onItems[j]
                            : offItems[j]);
    }
};
```

in OnCreateDialog:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();

        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

}

EDIT:
i finally know whats the problem is . threads are working fine and if i dont use animation, ui updates . when dialog starts showing . i start an animation and move ImageViews (cheatHoldrs) . after the animation ImageViews image does not changes .
i tried 9oldroid animation and TranslateAnimation like this but still dosent change ui after animation :
for api > 11 i use ObjectAnimator and it works fine , but for api < 11 i use this methods

```
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, forLeft, 0, 0);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setDuration(1000);

    cheatHoldrs[1].startAnimation(animation);
    TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, forLeft, 0, 0);
    animation2.setFillAfter(true);
    animation2.setDuration(1000);

    cheatHoldrs[2].startAnimation(animation2);

    TranslateAnimation animation3 = new TranslateAnimation(0, forRight, 0, 0);
    animation3.setFillAfter(true);
    animation3.setDuration(1000);

    cheatHoldrs[0].startAnimation(animation3);
```

and nineoldandroids method :

```
    com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator transitionForFirst = com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
            .ofFloat(cheatHoldrs[0], "translationX", forRight);
    transitionForFirst.setDuration(1000);

    com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator transitionForSecound = com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
            .ofFloat(cheatHoldrs[1], "translationX", forLeft);
    transitionForSecound.setDuration(1000);

    com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator transitionForThird = com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
            .ofFloat(che

atHoldrs[2], "translationX", forLeft);
        transitionForThird.setDuration(1000);

        transitionForFirst.start();
        transitionForSecound.start();
        transitionForThird.start();
```

Comment: Can you explain "not okay"? Is it crashing? Not showing? Something else?

Comment: its not crashing . it change the ui for once then ui wont change . meanwhile thread is still running